# Deserialize JSON to generic type

Tags: generics, kotlin, spring-kafka

I have a generic class to be deserialized from JSON. How do I configure JsonDeserializer in Kotlin?

```
org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

...

ErrorHandlingDeserializer2(JsonDeserializer(
        MyGenericClass<MyClass>::class.java,  // this throws "Only classes are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal" error
        objectMapper
))
```

I found solutions e.g. using `reified`, but I'm not able to apply it to this Spring Kafka JsonDeserializer.

Comment: Types erasure in Java does not let you have the `Generic<P>` like structures. The type will be only for the `Generic` class. You may capture the type by creating a non-generic object, e.g. `object: TypeReference<Generic<MyClass>> {}`. Try looking for something similar in Kafka sources, also you may use `reified` generics of Kotlin to simplify the way you create a TypeReference (or similar) objects
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be sure, do you mean to extend/write my own implementation of JsonDeserializer with TypeReference support?

Comment: That may work, but sometimes it may work too https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html